# How to add a user environment aware application launcher to unity panel?

Tags: 11.10, unity, launcher, environment-variables, netbeans

Here is my problem: When I search from Unity's Dash Home for NetBeans and drag&drop it to unity launcher it, I observed that netbeans does not have access to my environment variables which were defined in my `.bashrc` file as follows

```
... 
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/typesafe-stack
...
```

When I run NetBeans from the gnome-terminal I don't observe that problem about the environment variable.

I also made a desktop file instead. Here is how I defined my `netbeans.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=NetBeans IDE 7.0.1
Icon=/usr/local/netbeans-7.0.1/nb/netbeans.png
Exec=netbeans
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
StartupNotify=false
```

How can I modify this file so that it will be aware of the user's environment variables?

Thanks in advance,

Yours sincerely.

ciuncan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this:

```
SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/typesafe-stack
```

to this:

```
/etc/environment
```

Why the Unity launcher doesn't source the users environment from `.bashrc`, as it should IMO, is anyone's guess.

Comment: It isn't unity specific but rather the free desktop specs that most guis are now using.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting Terminal to "true":

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=NetBeans IDE 7.0.1
Icon=/usr/local/netbeans-7.0.1/nb/netbeans.png
Exec=netbeans
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
StartupNotify=false
```

I think this happens because the executable `netbeans` itself is not a `bash` script:

```
file `which netbeans` #shows the type of the file
head -n1 `which netbeans` #shows the first line of the file/script
```

(my bet is "POSIX shell script text executable", #!/bin/sh instead of #!/bin/bash)

Update: Also, try editing `.profile` file instead of .bashrc (and logout/login)